# Unresolved external symbols in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have three functions defined in a C++ Dll program developed under VS2010.

```
int __stdcall Scan()
{
...
}

int __stdcall Setup(int e_time, double s_value, double cs_value, double gain, int nIm, char* name) 
{
...
}

int __stdcall TearDown()
{
....
}
```

I defined them in Program.def as

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
   Scan @1
   Setup @2
   TearDown @3
```

I also have a headefile Program.h

```
//DLL Export-Import definitions
#define BUILD_DLL

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

But I am getting some errors:

- "49 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Scan  in Program.def line 1"
- "51 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Setup  in Program.def line 1"

and

- "51 error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals symbol in Program.lib"

Error message does not complain about the third function defined. I used /MAP option in the linker, and defined a file name for the map file, but I am not getting a MAP file output to check how these sysmbols are defined. I cannot use *dumpbin* program since build did not create a dll file yet.

I am stuck. Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mangle the function names? Where is the `extern "C"` or similar line to indicate not to mangle the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare C-style linkage or the C++ *name decoration* messes things up.

Use, for each function

```
extern "C" {
    /*your function here*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul and Bathsheba. extern "C" did it. No messing up now!